# bootstrap, form-inline как не переносить текст на новую строку?

Tags: bootstrap4

Мне нравится как работает form-inline, выравнивая элементы в строку, но как заставить последний span class="text-danger" на разных экранах вести себя по разному, если не вмещается в экран не переносить на новую строку, а оставлять в одной линии обрезая текст?
Как то вот так:http://prntscr.com/uer8ct
А сейчас он себя ведет вот так: http://prntscr.com/uer9i1

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-inline">
<span class="text-primary">content</span>
<span class="text-secondary">content content</span>
<span class="text-danger">content content content content</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 d-block text-truncate">
      <span class="text-primary">content</span>
      <span class="text-secondary">content content</span>
      <span class="text-danger">content content content content</span>
      </div>
```

Вот так?

Comment: неа, тоже не катит я пробовал, если размер экрана будет меньше то так же перейдет на следующую строку http://prntscr.com/uesr9o Мб можно сделать что бы текст просто за div блок\экран уходил не появлялась прокрутка по ширине? http://prntscr.com/uesu6l

Comment: @МихаилПетров  form-inline должен быть обязательно? если его убрать проблема решена

Comment: А что можно использовать заместо что бы добиться подобного эффекта?

Comment: @МихаилПетров https://i.imgur.com/kGx0jKi.png d-flex? да вернее даже обычный d-block

Comment: Это идеально! Спасибо d-flex прям то что надо, d-block все-таки переносит на другую строку